# How can I update a single field in an array of embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to update a field in an array of embedded documents.

My sample document is:

```
db.students.insert(
    {
        first_name:'AA',
        last_name:'BB',
        cours_reussis:[{intitule:'PAI',note:0,name_school:'EPFC'}]
    }
)
```

I'd like to change the value of `name_school` to "ENSA" instead of "EPFC".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It may need small modifications based on your other variables but I think this will work:

```
db.students.update(
   { first_name: 'AA' },
   { $set:
      {
        "cours_reussis.0.name_school": 'ENSA'
      }
   }
)
```

`cours_reussis` is an array. The 0 is the array index.

For your reference: [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Answer (score 19):

The answer from Kalhara is correct if you know the position of the embedded document in your array, however there is an alternative approach that can be used to update the first matching array element without knowing the position.

Assuming you update with a single array in your query criteria, the [positional operator (`$`)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) can be used to refer to the matching array element:

```
db.students.update(
    // Match criteria
    {
        first_name: 'AA',
        last_name: 'BB',
        'cours_reussis.name_school': 'EPFC'
    },

    // Update first matching array element using the positional operator ($)
    {
        $set: {
            'cours_reussis.$.name_school': 'ENSA',
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stennie
Unfortunately it does not work. It gives me this message

`WriteResult({
 "nMatched" : 0,
 "nUpserted" : 0,
 "nModified" : 0,
 "writeError" : {
  "code" : 16837,
  "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: cours_reussis.$.nom_ecole"
 }
})`


Sorry for my english i use google to translate

Comment: @zouhair The WriiteResult indicates that a matching document was not found, so you need to adjust your criteria. My update statement works for your sample document as included in the question description, but you'll have to modify to suit your current data. It looks like perhaps you need to change `name_school` in the update statement to `nom_ecole` to match your actual data,

Comment: this should be marked as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to update the first matching array element without knowing the index:

```
db.students.update(
    { first_name: 'AA',name_school:'EPFC' },
    { $set:
       {
         "cours_reussis.$.name_school": 'ENSA'
       }
    }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this to update the array element with some conditions and without knowing the index:*

```
db.getCollection('profiles').update(
  {
    'userId':'4360a380-1540-45d9-b902-200f2d346263',
    'skills.name':'css'
  },
  {
      $set: {'skills.$.proficiencyLevel': 5}
  }, 
  {
      multi: true
  }
)
```